# Свой ActionBar в Android

Tags: actionbar, мобильная-разработка, android, java

Всем привет.

Заинтересовался вопросом, можно ли в Android сделать собственный ActionBar?

Вот примерно как я это представляю

1. Добавить на все необходимые Activity некий LinearLayout.
2. Сделать его fixed, чтобы он не исчезал при прокрутке.
3. Добавить туда некоторые элементы, например, текст и иконки.
4. Собственно, обрабатывать нажатия по иконкам и выполнять определение действия.

Так можно? Или есть способ получше?

Если можно, то как сделать этот LinearLayout fixed и чтобы он не перекрывал первые элементы на Activity? (В css это, к примеру, делается все с помощью margin и fixed.)

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего, вас вполне устроит **Toolbar**: [ссылка на доки гугла](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html).

1. Его можно крепить куда-угодно в иерархии вьюшек.
2. Можно назначить ActionBar-ом, и он будет хватать стандартные для него события (клик по меню, например).
3. При этом это ViewGroup со всеми её возможностями.
4. Ну и в supportLib оно тоже присутствует.

**Обновление**

[[@M11](/users/15504/m11)](/users/15504/m11), да, появилось недавно.

Примеры точно есть, вроде даже на хабре что-то было.

Попробуйте пользовать [суппорт-версию тулбара](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html]), т.е. в xml объявляйте так:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб насколько я понял, оно только вышло недавно? Не могу никаких примеров найти. И eclipse ругается на то, что он с АПИ 21, а у меня минимальный 8. Конечно, может что-то не так подключил.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ваш ответ очень полезен. думаю многим будет. вот собственно и статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/241479/ . Если честно не очень понял. Вполне возможно из-за того что я меньше месяца в такой разработке. А статья написана на более опытных. А больше на русском не нашел. Впрочем и вопрос состоит так это сделать самому. Хотя меня этот метод очень за интересовал и возможно я б ним и воспользовался. Только проблемы разные появились. Например метод Toolbar не находит и импортировать не предлагает. Попробую обновить пакеты в eclipse. Не могли бы пожалуйста помочь?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать кастомный [actionbar.setCustomView()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(int))